# LAN local IP Address using Javascript for Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, ip-address

I want to know LAN local Ip address (192.168.XXX.XXX) of machine using **Javascript** for **Safari Browser**.

On Chrome & Firefox, I am able to do it with **WebRTC**. But Safari doesn't support it. Any workaround for Safari browser?

Comment: maybe you can guess and check. `new Image().src="http://193.168.0.1"` timed out but `new Image().src="http://192.168.0.1"` failed right away, and `http://192.168.0.102/` made an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` that others didn't. guess which one is my local IP? look into timing attacks

Comment: @dandavis: Yea, good idea. Ping all possible local IP's 'till one responds. You'd have to cover `10.0.0.1` to `10.255.255.254`, `172.16.0.1` to `172.31.255.254` and `192.168.0.1` to `192.168.255.254`. That's **`17.548.080`** addresses.

Comment: @Cerbrus: yeah, if you want to be sure, but i bet i could make 50-100 pings and hit 80% of devices... i'm actually ok with that because a common IP is no secret anyway... font fingerprinting is where the privacy intrusion hits hardest in JS...

Comment: ___50___ pings. Possibly 50 failed requests. I can't begin to tell you how insane the idea is.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it's more of a wise-guy response to be sure, but i have heard of actual attacks using such techniques to map out an internal network. HuffPost makes hundreds of pings to show an article, who's going to notice 50 here or there. way fewer if you guess well. again, not super handy, but i do want folks to be aware that this nefariousness is possible. I think they also removed the easy way to get IP from RTC... http://2011.appsecusa.org/p/pwn.pdf

Comment: _"Attacks"_, exactly. A news website with a large load of images, social plugins, tracking scripts etc isn't a very good example of a website that has many requests. Most of those can be blocked while still being able to read the article.

Comment: And trust me, users _will_ notice a website polling local addresses. 50 failed requests? All pointing to sequential local IPs? I wouldn't be surprised if that results in the site being blocked by anti-malware plugins, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this kind of data is not accessible through JavaScript.

Frankly, websites have no business poking around in data like that.